# Setting default language in EPiServer?

Tags: c#, .net, episerver

I'm looking for a way to set the default language for visitors comming to a site built in EPiServer for the first time. Not just administrators/editors in the backend, people comming to the public site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your setup.

If the site languages is to change under different domains you can do this.
Add to configuration -> configSections nodes in web.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="episerver">
  <section name="domainLanguageMappings" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" allowLocation="false" type="EPiServer.Util.DomainLanguageConfigurationHandler,EPiServer" />
```

..and add this to episerver node in web.config:

```
  <domainLanguageMappings>
    <map domain="site.com" language="EN" />
    <map domain="site.se" language="SV" />
  </domainLanguageMappings>
```

Otherwhise you can do something like this.
Add to appSettings in web.config:

```
<add name="EPsDefaultLanguageBranch" key="EN"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this on EPiServer CMS5:

```
<globalization culture="sv-SE" uiCulture="sv" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" resourceProviderFactoryType="EPiServer.Resources.XmlResourceProviderFactory, EPiServer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In EPiServer CMS 5, add the following setting to your web.config:

```
<site description="Example Site">
    <siteHosts>
         <add name="www.site.se" language="sv" />
         <add name="www.site.no" language="no" />
         <add name="www.site.co.uk" language="en-GB" />
         <add name="*" />
    </siteHosts>
```

The language choosen for the start page is depending on the host header in the request.

If you set attribute `pageUseBrowserLanguagePreferences="true"` in your siteSettings tag in web.config the browsers request may be used to select language for the startpage.